# unexpected ApplicationSupport alias in ~/Library

Tags: library

I've noticed a weird alias in `~/Library`. It's `ApplicationSupport` (no space), pointing to the good old `Application Support` (with a space).

```
$ cd ~/Library
$ ls -l | grep Support
drwx------+ 111 myuser  staff   3552 11 Oct 23:10 Application Support
lrwxr-xr-x    1 myuser  staff     38  2 Aug 11:28 ApplicationSupport -> /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support
```

I don't know where it comes from, and I didn't create it myself. Does anyone know if it gets created by a specific app installation? Is there a way to verify it?

I guess I could rename it and delete it and see if anything breaks.

Comment: 1. That is not an _alias_, it's a _symlink_, and while similar they are not the same. 2. If you do not remember creating it, then I'd just delete it. If some other app created it, it will probably recreate it, and if it does, then I'd investigate it further.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks. Yes, I know it's a symlink, and I know I can delete it and see what happens. I was hoping someone knew what application usually creates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alias is created by iTerm2. There's a ticket about this :

Maintainer:

> Sorry for the inconvenience. It has come to my attention that some people find this annoying. It's necessary for the Python API, but you can change the name of the alias or remove it completely with this setting in 3.3.3beta1:

The setting *Create a Symlink in "Application Support" with this name* being in Advanced" tab in App preferences.

https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/8141#note_205533333

Comment: Hi there! thanks for pointing to the appropriate site. Links are often not very helpful.